# How do I upgrade my office?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I'm in the first office. It's year 30, I have 121.6K fans and plenty of money. I've been in office 1 since year 3 and, after 27 years, and I would really like a nicer place.

What do I need to be able to upgrade and how do I do it?

Comment: @Studoku Not going to say anything **NICE** don't say **ANYTHING AT ALL**

Comment: The question is fine, why the downvotes? The comments he made were a response to a rather offensive one by Studoku that is now deleted.

Comment: There's a tooltip on the up vote and down vote buttons that gives some possible reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Your office level can be increased through research when you meet the prerequisites- usually time, money and number of employees. This will get you a nicer office.

If you are at level 2 (the first real office), the upgrade becomes available in Y11 if you have two staff and $5 million. This upgrade is easy to miss, however, since it doesn't change the building.

If you're actually at level 3, you need 4 staff and $13 million to upgrade.

Source: http://gamedevtycoon.wikia.com/wiki/Research_Unlocks#Office_Level